# OpenXML data from excel to powerpoint

Tags: c#, openxml

Can I use OpenXML to transfer a table from excel to powerpoint presentation, and if yes how? I can't find any code in the web doing that. I have only found parts that export charts to powerpoint, but I want to copy rows from tables and keep formatting (colors, styles) and export it to powerpoint. Thanks for your help

Comment: Copy & Paste will do the trick... ? no ?

Comment: @vil.coyote.ch Thanks for your suggestion but I want to do it using openxml and C#

Answer (score 1):

You can parse OpenXML with [Open XML SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/open-xml-sdk)  :

```
WorkbookPart workbookPart = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart;
WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookPart.WorksheetParts.First();
SheetData sheetData = worksheetPart.Worksheet.Elements<SheetData>().First();
string text;
foreach (Row r in sheetData.Elements<Row>())
{
    foreach (Cell c in r.Elements<Cell>())
    {
        text = c.CellValue.Text;
        // Make some usefule here
    }
}
```

([Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/how-to-parse-and-read-a-large-spreadsheet))

Then use this code: [How to add a table with rows to PowerPoint using open xml](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/How-to-add-a-table-with-03578dde) to create Table in powerpoint

Comment: Thank you . I will try your solution and if it works I will accept your answer.

Comment: It is very close to what I want but not exactly. I saw the link that you suggested in an earlier search of mine. I tried your solution but the result isn't identical to the excel table. I lose colors , borders. I would like it to be like a copy / paste if that's possible.

Comment: Yes, you are right... I was too excited to post my first answer... ;-)